# delete node from linked list and push into stack using alloy analyser

Tags: alloy

I want to delete an Element from Linked List and Push it on Stack.I tried to write this code.
I was writing the code to push the element into stack but it is giving error.
That code is in comment.

//Doubly Linked list

```
sig node{}
sig list
{
    elts: set node,
    next: elts lone->lone elts,
    prev: elts lone->lone elts,
    first: one node,
    last: one node
} 
{
    all x:elts | x not in x.^next
    all x:elts | x not in x.^prev
    no first.prev
    no last.next

    first.^next=elts-first
    last.^prev=elts-last
    all x,x1:elts | (x.next=x1) =>(x1.prev=x)
}
```

//stack

```
one sig Null extends node{}

sig stack
{
    elts: set node,
    top: one elts,
    next: elts lone ->lone elts
} 
{
    all e:elts | all l:list | all l1:l.elts | l1 not in e
    all e:elts | e not in e.^next
    no Null.next
    top.^next=elts-top
    Null in elts
} 
pred undo(beforelist,afterlist:list,beforestack,afterstack:stack)
{
```

i have tried this code(in comment) to insert the element in stack.
but this gives no instance found error.

```
/*
    afterstack.elts=beforestack.elts+(beforelist.last)
    beforelist.last=afterstack.top
    afterstack.next=beforestack.next+(beforelist.last->beforestack.top)
*/  

    //afterstack.elts=(beforestack.elts)+(beforelist.last)

        afterlist.elts=beforelist.elts-beforelist.last
        afterlist.last=beforelist.last.(beforelist.prev)
    }
run undo for 2 list,2 stack, 5 node
```

Answer (score 0):

"No instance found" is not an error, it just an outcome of the analysis.

In your case, it is unable to find an instance because of these two competing constraints

```
// inside appended facts for sig stack
all e:elts | all l:list | all l1:l.elts | l1 not in e
```

and

```
afterstack.elts=beforestack.elts+(beforelist.last)
```

The first one says that no stack may share a node with any list.  The second one explicitly says that the elements of `afterstack` must include the last node of `beforelist`.

I think you should remove the first fact and write it as a predicate which you can then assert on a given (`node`, `list`) pair (or a set of pairs), since, I assume, your goal is to say that in the "before" state that constraint hods, as well as in the "after" state.

Comment: i am not able to write that assertion.
i tried it, but that code make stack elements and list elements same.
that i dont want.
i want both stack and list to be separate.
can you give me the code?

Comment: Then just remove that fact.

Comment: then stack will point to some element in list.
i want the output that will display both stack and list separated.

Comment: You can configure your output to show only atoms from the "after" state, in which you won't have shared nodes between `afterstack` and `afterlist`